# COMRESET Failed errno-16

Tags: ssd, 18.10

I read some of the topics related to the same problem, but have an additional behavior.

Experiencing mentioned issue.
Notebook Asus VivoBook s15 s530u

Ubuntu 18.10 with kernel 4.18.0-13 generic.

Start point - replacement of HDD by SSD.

Installed SSD = ADATA SU800 512 GB;

SSD is mounted as /home

How it happens - randomly.
What is going on - Some application freezes (last time it was Chrome, before that - system PDF reader). Ubuntu throws the message that application X is not responding and two options "Wait" or "Force Quit". Not depending on choice, my new one SSD is remounted as read-only disk. I can access and open the files, but can't create or write.

At the end: If I reboot - I receive COMRESET error and later journalctl writes that `/home` was not mounted and drops me in grub. Another reboot return the same issue, but if I shutdown and then startup the notebook - everything is going fine and fast.

fchk - no mistakes;
smartctl - no mistakes in long selftest;
BIOS is updated;
Ubuntu is reinstalled (in total with disks formatted);

I can try to update SSD firmware but this should be done under Windows (no Linux updater) and I, actually, don't wont to open notebook once again, but if this the only option...

Firmware update is not an option as I have the latest one.

Concerning the possibility to read files - I was wrong about that. I can read files only from Download folder. I think that this folder is shared somehow, as it should be accessible for applications from system SSD.

Answer (score 1):

Short reply: remove optical drive and system boots normally.

I've been having the same hassle with a Samsung 350V Laptop. I revived it with a new battery and SSD, and installed Manjaro Linux. Occasionally I'd start getting the COMRESET error slowing my boot time down by a minute. I noticed that the Samsung splash screen during bios would hang for 20 seconds when the machine was in this state. The optical drive also made an audible reset when the system was booting normally. I searched every forum post on this issue and none of them seemed to resolve it conclusively.

I was able to get my system up and running a few times by unplugging the drive, doing a power cycle, even re-seating the RAM, but every time it came online after a different combination of repeated attempts, and the definitive solution eluded me.

Then I found the following link:

https://forum.hddguru.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=35309&view=previous

This put me onto the idea that it could be a power issue, despite SSD's using less power than HDD's (?)

I simply removed the optical drive and the system booted perfectly. Replaced and it still works fine. Remove SSD and replace... COMRESET error. Remove optical drive... Problem solved again. I'm still holding thumbs but it's been a couple of days and I have been able to repeat the sequence reliably thus far.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't have one. Already removed the SSD and checking it with windows - for now everything is Ok. Don't now what the reason.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was afraid my hdd died, but after plugging out the cdrom drive (that I haven't used for years!), everything was fine again.